# Javascript form validation returning false, but the form still submits

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to validate a form with javascript. The function gets called properly and the alert is displayed, but the form is still submitted after I click ok on the alert. The function never returns false. I have seen this question asked before, but I have not seen an answer that worked. I am using some JQuery mobile in this and that may be the problem. I have tried to change the button input type=button, but that would not even submit the form.

The javascript function is:

```
<script>
function validateInventoryform()
{
var sku=document.getElementById('sku_checkbox');
var entire=document.getElementById('entire_checkbox');
var inv=document.getElementById('inv');
if ((sku.checked==true && entire.checked==true))
 {
alert("You may only choose one option to check customer inventory");
return false;
 }
}
</script>
```

The form is:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupQuery_inventory" data-theme='a' > 
  <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
    <form action="inventory_inquiry.php" method="get" id="inv" onsubmit="return validateInventoryform()" >           
     <h3>Enter SKU</h3>
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
        <legend>Choose Input Type:</legend>
          <input type="checkbox" data-theme="a" name="sku_checkbox" id="sku_checkbox" value="off" checked="checked">
          <label for="sku_checkbox">SKU</label>
          <input type="checkbox" data-theme="a" name="entire_checkbox" id="entire_checkbox" value="off">
         <label for="entire_checkbox">Entire Inventory</label>
         </fieldset>

            <label for="sku" class="ui-hidden-accessible">SKU:</label>
            <input type="text" name="sku" id="sku" value="" placeholder="Item SKU" data-theme="a">
            <input name="customer_id" type="hidden" value='<?php echo $customer_id; ?>'/>
           <button type="submit" data-theme="b"/>Submit</button>
        </form>    
   </div>
</div>
```

I am adding the href that calls up the popup for the form. I don't know if that has anything to do with this problem. I keep hearing that my code is being replicated and it is working just fine. I can't get it to work and I want to represent the issue in its entirety.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="b">
    <li><a href="#popupCustomer_alert" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="origin" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop" >Add Customer Alert</a></li>
    <li><a href="#popupQuery_inventory" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="origin" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop" >Query Inventory</a></li>
    <li><a href="#popupEdit_customer" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="origin" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop" >Edit Customer</a></li>
    <li><a href="return_qr_code.php" >Get QR Code</a></li>
    <li><a href="#popupDownload_inventory" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="origin" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop" >Download Inventory</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try to avoid inline JS. You could use JQuery `submit` event instead. It works with JQuery Mobile.

Comment: does it show your alert?

Comment: I will try that. This does not work no matter what changes I make.

Comment: your code works fine for me

Comment: I do get the alert. It still submits the form, though.

Comment: I am using Safari, but I get the same result in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding return true at last line of validateInventoryform() and remove extra "/" in this

```
 <button type="submit" data-theme="b"/>Submit</button>
```

try Jquery to bind event

```
$(function () {
        $('#form').bind('submit', function (e) {
            var isValid = true;
            if (!isValid) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I added return true and it still submits the form. I will try the Jquery submit. There must be something not playing well with the Jquery mobile pieces of this site.

Comment: This worked. I tried everything else and this is the only thing that worked. I suspect that it had to do with the Jquery mobile components.

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you validate the form before it is submitted. Do the validation on button click.

Or better yet, use radio buttons instead of checkboxes since you only want to allow one option to be selected:

```
<input type="radio" data-theme="a" name="input_type" id="sku_checkbox" value="SKU" />
<input type="radio" data-theme="a" name="input_type" id="entire_checkbox" value="Entire Inventory" />
```

Comment: Radio buttons...it seems like I should have thought of that. I still run into the issue when I want to validate a form for blank inputs, though. The form validation just does not seem to work.

Comment: Well if you use radio buttons, you don't need the validation that checks for only one option anymore.

Comment: I tried the radio buttons and I can still choose both options.

Comment: Ow... make sure that they have the same `name`, otherwise, it will not work.

Comment: The same name. That is what I was missing.

Comment: Yes, it will work now. I can bypass the validation for this part. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Below coding is working perfectly:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>checkbox</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validateInventoryform()
 {
var sku=document.getElementById('sku_checkbox');
var entire=document.getElementById('entire_checkbox');
var inv=document.getElementById('inv');
if ((sku.checked==true && entire.checked==true))
 {
alert("You may only choose one option to check customer inventory");
return false;
 }
}
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupQuery_inventory" data-theme='a' > 
  <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
    <form action="inventory_inquiry.php" method="get" id="inv" onsubmit="return validateInventoryform()" >           
     <h3>Enter SKU</h3>
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
        <legend>Choose Input Type:</legend>
          <input type="checkbox" data-theme="a" name="sku_checkbox" id="sku_checkbox" value="off" checked="checked">
          <label for="sku_checkbox">SKU</label>
          <input type="checkbox" data-theme="a" name="entire_checkbox" id="entire_checkbox" value="off">
         <label for="entire_checkbox">Entire Inventory</label>
         </fieldset>

            <label for="sku" class="ui-hidden-accessible">SKU:</label>
            <input type="text" name="sku" id="sku" value="" placeholder="Item SKU" data-theme="a">
            <input name="customer_id" type="hidden" value='<?php echo $customer_id; ?>'/>
           <button type="submit" data-theme="b"/>Submit</button>
        </form>    
   </div>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: I have tested this on a Mac and a PC for Chrome and Safari. Neither of them worked for me. Something else is happening here.

Comment: Could there be anything with the href that calls the popup? I just added that code to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and I hope this is what you are looking for:

Html:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupQuery_inventory" data-theme='a' > 
  <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
    <form action="inventory_inquiry.php" method="get" id="inv">           
     <h3>Enter SKU</h3>
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
        <legend>Choose Input Type:</legend>
            <input type="radio" data-theme="a" name="input_type" id="sku_checkbox" value="SKU" />SKU
            <input type="radio" data-theme="a" name="input_type" id="entire_checkbox" value="Entire Inventory" />Entire Inventory
         </fieldset>

            <label for="sku" class="ui-hidden-accessible">SKU:</label>
            <input type="text" name="sku" id="sku" value="" placeholder="Item SKU" data-theme="a" />
            <input name="customer_id" type="hidden" value='<?php echo $customer_id; ?>'/>
            <input type="button" data-theme="b" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" />
        </form>    
   </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#submitBtn").on("click", function(event){
    //Your validation code here
    if($("#sku").val() == ""){
        alert("Item sku is null")
    } else {
        // Submit event if everything is okey
        $("#inv").submit();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8aapR/

Answer (score 0):

I am using same html and script code provided by you and tested in all browser and it is working fine.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
    function validateInventoryform()
    {
    var sku=document.getElementById('sku_checkbox');
    var entire=document.getElementById('entire_checkbox');
    var inv=document.getElementById('inv');
    if ((sku.checked==true && entire.checked==true))
     {
    alert("You may only choose one option to check customer inventory");
    return false;
     }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupQuery_inventory" data-theme='a' > 
      <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
        <form action="inventory_inquiry.php" method="get" id="inv" onsubmit="return validateInventoryform()" >           
         <h3>Enter SKU</h3>
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
            <legend>Choose Input Type:</legend>
              <input type="checkbox" data-theme="a" name="sku_checkbox" id="sku_checkbox" value="off" checked="checked">
              <label for="sku_checkbox">SKU</label>
              <input type="checkbox" data-theme="a" name="entire_checkbox" id="entire_checkbox" value="off">
             <label for="entire_checkbox">Entire Inventory</label>
             </fieldset>

                <label for="sku" class="ui-hidden-accessible">SKU:</label>
                <input type="text" name="sku" id="sku" value="" placeholder="Item SKU" data-theme="a">
                <input name="customer_id" type="hidden" value='<?php echo $customer_id; ?>'/>
               <button type="submit" data-theme="b"/>Submit</button>
            </form>    
       </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I am still researching this. I tried it on Chrome and Safari and both on Mac and a PC. Neither option works for me. This is strange.